# 301 Redirect in Codeigniter using php / mysql

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

We have recently edited our site to remove several thousand pages. Some of these pages were items we no longer wish to display, others are duplicates of same item (ie www.site.com/item, www.site.com/category/item). We are trying to clean up our site to minimize duplicate content for SEO purposes.

We use Codeigniter on an NGINX server.  Since i have several thousand pages i wish to redirect (either to a 404 page or a different valid page), I want to avoid editing the config files with all these redirect rules.

The solution I am trying to get to work involves checking a DB table for invalid_url and if it is in the table, redirect to valid_url.  However, i am not certain a) how to check for this before a page loads, and b) whether Codeigniter has a built in controller for this.

Has anyone done something like this before and can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a) how to check for this before a page loads

Just do the check before you do anything else in the controller function you are calling. The page isn't loaded until the server says it is. If you are doing this lookup, the page hasn't loaded until it finishes and renders or redirects.

> and b) whether Codeigniter has a built in controller for this

No, but you can use the [url helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) `redirect()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to:

1. Have custom Controller class to extend native `CI_Controller`
2. Use it for your existing controller(s)
3. Use `__construct()` method to check all the incoming queries and redirect if needed